# After deployment from dev sandbox to test sandbox via change sets, Path is not working as expected

Tags: pathassistant, path

After deployment from dev sandbox to test sandbox via change sets, Path is not working as expected...

On DEV environment I am able to click on that arrow and it displays fields(3), that I want. But after deployment via change sets to test sandbox, I am not able to click on that arrow. Anyone know where should be the problem?

Thank you.

[image: Path]

Answer (score 1):

Deploying Path does not always work as expected. Highly recommend to manually create on target org instead of deploy. You will find that re-creating manually saves more time than figuring out why the deployment errors for PathAssistant didn't get through properly.

Case in point ->

1. ["Required field missing: PicklistMasterId" error when deploying a path from a sandbox to another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/226329/38191)
2. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gWXQAY